# How to collapse data while retaining other variables?

Tags: sas

I am trying to collapse my data using proc sql. However, i noticed that when I tried to collapse my data I lost a bunch of variables that I wanted to keep. I am trying to collapse my data based on the variable MRN (which is numeric). The other variables I want to keep are CITY and SITE (these are character values) and these are constant for each unique MRN, so collapsing them should be fine.

Here is the code I am using

```
proc sql;
    create table collapsed_data  as 
        select distinct mrn,
            sum(msk_tx_yes) as msk_tx_yes,
            sum(msk_cancel_tx_yes) as msk_cancel_tx_yes,
            sum(msk_ca_yes) as msk_ca_yes, 
            sum(msk_cancel_ca_yes) as msk_cancel_ca_yes, 
            sum(msk_dc_yes) as msk_dc_yes,
            sum(conc_psych_tx_yes) as conc_psych_tx_yes,
            sum(conc_psych_ca_yes) as conc_psych_ca_yes,
            sum (conc_psych_dc_yes) as conc_psych_dc_yes,
            sum (conc_yes) as conc_yes,
            sum (psych_yes) as psych_yes,
            sum (foot_prog) as foot_prog,
            sum (hand_prog) as hand_prog,
            sum (surg_prog) as surg_prog,
            sum (sx_yes) as sx_yes
        from temp_collapsed_data
        group by mrn;
quit;
```

I'm not sure how to use the SELECT and DISTINCT functions together.

I thought maybe I could add the variables CITY and STATE after SELECT, while keeping DISTINCT but it doens't sem to work.

I want to be able to keep CITY and STATE in the new table along with the new summed variables I am making. How can I achieve this without turning CITY and STATE into dummy coded variables? I would like to keep them as character values if possible.

Anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Yur code is already correct. Just add the variables to the select statement.

```
proc sql;
    create table collapsed_data  as 
        select distinct mrn, city, site,
            sum(msk_tx_yes) as msk_tx_yes,
            sum(msk_cancel_tx_yes) as msk_cancel_tx_yes,
            sum(msk_ca_yes) as msk_ca_yes, 
            sum(msk_cancel_ca_yes) as msk_cancel_ca_yes, 
            sum(msk_dc_yes) as msk_dc_yes,
            sum(conc_psych_tx_yes) as conc_psych_tx_yes,
            sum(conc_psych_ca_yes) as conc_psych_ca_yes,
            sum (conc_psych_dc_yes) as conc_psych_dc_yes,
            sum (conc_yes) as conc_yes,
            sum (psych_yes) as psych_yes,
            sum (foot_prog) as foot_prog,
            sum (hand_prog) as hand_prog,
            sum (surg_prog) as surg_prog,
            sum (sx_yes) as sx_yes
        from temp_collapsed_data
        group by mrn;
quit;
```

The distinct statement will result in not having two rows with the same information.